# The driver executable does not exist: D:\workspace\sample\?D:\workspace\sample\Driver\chromedriver.exe

Tags: selenium-webdriver

The driver executable does not exist: D:\workspace\sample\?D:\workspace\sample\Driver\chromedriver.exe. Not getting why this error is coming while running selenium webdriver.

Comment: does the driver executable exist?

Comment: yes. Path is D:\workspace\sample\Driver\chromedriver.exe

Comment: Try setting the driver executable in your environment variable `PATH`. It should make it work.

Comment: plz provide script